# Is the rewriting of speaking URLs in 9LTS supposed to work out of the box on IIS?

Tags: iis, typo3, slug, iis-8.5, typo3-9.x

We are testing an upgrade from Typo3 8LTS to 9LTS and speaking URLs seem to work in typo3 itself, but the server returns a 404. Is the rewriting of URLs supposed to work out of the box on IIS? Or do we need to add some extra configuration manually,  e.g. to the Web.config?

We tried the official documentation but there is only some information about an Apache server. And google was of no help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-web-config` you can find a demo IIS configuration. I assume this part is missing in your TYPO3 installation.

Comment: I'm just starting to test, but it works perfektly so far. Thank you for your help!

Comment: And now I found the info accidentally in a different part of the typo3 dokumentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.5/Important-86173-LocationOfSuppliedHtaccessWebconfigFilesChanged.html#

Comment: Then it would be good for others if you could mark the answer as helpful/correct.